# /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, syntax, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There must be something misconfigured with this system because the same code builds on other systems no problem. Here's the full output. Using Ubuntu 14.04 and the latest ros-indigo packages from the ppa. This is a fresh install on this system. Any ideas what it might be?

```
[ 17%] Built target bond_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target bond_generate_messages_py
[ 17%] Built target bond_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 17%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 17%] Scanning dependencies of target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target mbot_pure_pursuit
[ 17%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target velodyne_pointcloud_gencfg
Scanning dependencies of target velodyne_launch_generate_messages_py
[ 19%] Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/VelodyneConfig.cfg: /home/marble/mBot/ros/devel/include/velodyne_pointcloud/VelodyneConfigConfig.h /home/marble/mBot/ros/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_pointcloud/cfg/VelodyneConfigConfig.py
[ 19%] /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make[2]: *** [/home/marble/mBot/ros/devel/include/velodyne_pointcloud/VelodyneConfigConfig.h] Error 2
make[1]: *** [velodyne_driver_16/velodyne_pointcloud/CMakeFiles/velodyne_pointcloud_gencfg.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Built target velodyne_launch_generate_messages_py
```

Here's the cfg file in question. It starts with a shebang as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
PACKAGE = "velodyne_pointcloud"

from math import pi
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *

gen = ParameterGenerator()

gen.add("min_range", double_t, 0, "min range to publish", 0.9, 0.9, 10.0)
gen.add("max_range", double_t, 0, "max range to publish", 130, 0.9, 200)
gen.add("view_direction", double_t, 0, "angle defining the center of view",
        0.0, -pi, pi)
gen.add("view_width", double_t, 0, "angle defining the view width",
        2*pi, 0.0, 2*pi)

exit(gen.generate(PACKAGE, "velodyne_pointcloud", "VelodyneConfig"))
```

---

[Originally posted]([https://answers.ros.org/question/233201//bin/sh:-1:-syntax-error:-"("-unexpected/)](https://answers.ros.org/question/233201//bin/sh:-1:-syntax-error:-%22(%22-unexpected/)) by [zacwitte](https://answers.ros.org/users/26086/zacwitte/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2016-04-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-29**:\

> [..] and the latest ros-indigo packages from the ppa.

Just making sure: there is no PPA for ROS. Do you mean `packages.ros.org`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-29**:
Also: how did you download the sources for `velodyne`? DynReCfg files should be executable, so if you didn't clone the repository correctly, you can run into problems.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-04-29**:
You said you installed from "the ppa", but your output looks like you are building it from source. Are you?

**Comment by [zacwitte](https://answers.ros.org/users/26086/zacwitte/) on 2016-05-02**:
Yeah, sorry for the confusion. By "from the PPA" I mean I added packages.ros.org as a repository and most of ROS is installed that way. The velodyne package is out of date on packages.ros.org so I cloned the latest from github into a catkin workspace, which I'm trying to build.

**Comment by [glm](https://answers.ros.org/users/34037/glm/) on 2019-08-23**:
Missing shebang causes this same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the problem here was a space in my "actual" catkin workspace path. The path shown above is `/home/marble/mBot/ros/devel/include/velodyne_pointcloud/VelodyneConfigConfig.h` but that's actually a symlink to `/home/marble/Dropbox (my company)/mBot/ros/devel/include/velodyne_pointcloud/VelodyneConfigConfig.h`. Unfortunately dropbox has a space in the folder name and no way to change it. I thought a symlink would work fine and it usually does, but in this case it does not.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Dynamic Reconfigure, but the workaround for now is to not allow any spaces in paths, even if they're obscured by a symlink.

---

Originally posted by [zacwitte](https://answers.ros.org/users/26086/zacwitte/) with karma: 170 on 2016-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-05-02**:
I highly recommend that you avoid whitespace in your paths. It's just going to make your life easier.

**Comment by [zacwitte](https://answers.ros.org/users/26086/zacwitte/) on 2016-05-03**:
I definitely agree, however Dropbox doesn't offer a choice.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-05-05**:
It would be nice for `gencfg` to work even with spaces in the path, but that's hard to do for most Unix tools.